# Is there a way to permit the display of the browser's scrollbar with cappuccino?

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

The question says it all; I'm interested in using Cappuccino to make layout simpler for me, so I'd like to keep the browser scrollbar active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, Cappuccino implements its own scrollbars for added control.
Abandoning that would mean we lose that control.

The scrollbars are themeable though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just figured out that the browser scrollbar conflicts with Cappuccino's ideology. Personally I'd like to see it as an option, but it really is better for sites that need standard browser functionality to use html+css instead of an app framework like Cappuccino.